# Remove certain element from PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

As I am not very good with explaining things, I want to start with the code below:

```
     public function meta ( ) {
            $keywords_arr = $this->keywords();  
           /*
            echo "<pre>"; print_r($keywords_arr);die;
            gives following output:
            Array
            (
               [0] => f
               [1] => Business
               [2] => AP Online Top Business Short Headlines
               [3] => AP Online
            )

           */              

            $focuskw  = is_array($keywords_arr[0]) ? $keywords_arr[0] : null;
            return array(
                    '_yoast_wpseo_focuskw' => $focuskw          
            );
}
```

So now my question, is there any way i can eliminate the useless items from keyword array.

So that I can get some meaningful word that I can set as focused keyword.

In this case the first item "f" (but it can be any item) and i cannot set "F" as focused keyword.

So How to eliminate such meaningless items from array without adding complexity(i.e probably not running loop). I am not sure if it is possible.

I hope I am a bit more clear now.

Thank you

Comment: You’ll need to properly define what exactly makes an item “useless” first.

Comment: Why not use a loop and `unset` what you don't need?

Comment: I think you are looking for https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php (in your case). But try to use https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php in general

Comment: Once you can answer @CBroe's question, you may use [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to match that criteria and remove it.

Comment: Useless mean item with single character only for this case.  I just want to check other options than running a loop.

Comment: I have edited the question